# Working with Strings and Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

I am creating a program that would check the possible airlines that will travel from the starting airport to the destination airport (both of these info will be entered by the user). I have a file that contains all of the airline #'s along with their corresponding airports. For example, `10A, LIM, LAX` has the airline number (10A), the origin airport (LIM), and the destination airport (LAX). Each line contains the information following that format of airline #, origin airport (abbreviations), and the destination airport (abbreviations).

I will make C read the file and it will use the `fgets` function to read each line until it reaches the line that matches both the origin and destination airport. Then, it will return the airline number. If there isn't any, then the computer will print out that no airlines have that flight. Since each line will be considered as one string that will be stored in a character array that I have called as `str[10000]`. I want the airline number to be stored by using the `strcat` function. What I was thinking of doing is `strcat(str[0], str[1])` which would add in, for example using the example that I have with 10A is combine 10 (which would be stored in str[0]) and A (which would be stored in str[1]). This approach does not seem to be working for some reason.

I have created the function `void route(char *origin, char *destination, char *airline[])` to print out the airline number, but I don't know how to work with the array and store them into `*airline[]`. I have also initialized to be `*airline[20]` because there can be several airlines that go from the origin to the destination that the user specified.

I just want to make sure that I can ultimately use `strcmp` to compare what the user inputted for the origin and destination airports so that if it matches the airline number will be the reported.

Please help me with working with strings and arrays. When I try to compile and run the program, I get the error `Abort Trap 6` after I enter the origin and the destination airports. I don't know why this happens. I will appreciate any help that anyone has to offer. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Here is the function that I think the main problem is coming out from...

```
void route(char *origin, char *destination, char *airline[])
{
    char str[10000];

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL)

    strcat(str[0], str[1]); // Combining the first element (10) with second element (A)
}
```

*Please note that this code is still incomplete, but this where I am up to so far because I am stuck.*

**EDIT** 10A is not a possible choice for airline number. It does have three elements and all of the airline choices have only two elements, such as, 3A.

**EDIT** I added the line that uses the `fgets` function: `while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL)`

Comment: Yes, you can use `strcmp` to compare two strings.  If you want any help with debugging, you need to post a  [mcve] because we cannot read your mind and tell you why your program is wrong.  I would suggest editing your question to have a lot less text; just post a brief description of your goal, the minimal code that exhibits the problem, say what output you expected, and say what output you got.

Comment: `strcat(str[0], str[1]);` is certainly a problem. `str*` works with strings, but you supply individual characters. Did you mean `str[0] = str[1];` instead? That's still wrong as `str` is uninitialized. But I assume there is more code in which you initialize it?

Comment: "_10 (which would be stored in str[0])_" - Nope. You can't do that. `10` consist of _two_ characters `1` and `0` and they need to be stored in different variables. You can't store many values in a single variable, right? Maybd you need `str[strchr(str, ',') - str] = '\0';`?

Comment: When I printed out the value of `str[0]` I got the first element of every line of the file. When I printed out the value of `str[1]`, I got the second element of every line of the line - which was what I was looking for. Yes, that `strcat` function is definitely the problem. I forgot to add my fgets line where I find the size of `str`. Also, I realized that 10A is not a possible option in my file, there are actually only two elements and not three. My bad.

Comment: You can `sscanf` out the relevant data like so: `char plane[20], origin[20], dest[20]; if(sscanf(str, "%19[^,], %19[^,], %19s", plane, origin, dest) == 3){ /* Successfully extracted everything */ } else { /* Failed to extract the 3 items */ }`

Comment: This is the line I forgot to add: `while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL)`

Comment: @McYintosh Just extract the data from `str` into different variables using `sscanf` and you'll find everything to be much easier. BTW, 10000 seems a bit too excessive. I suggest lowering it to say, 1000.

Comment: @CoolGuy In my class we haven't learned about using the `sscanf` function, so I am a bit hesitant about using that. Any other method for a beginner C student?

Comment: Can you use `strtok`? Or `fscanf`? And if you could post the entire code ([mcve], preferably), you'd get better responses.

Comment: `fscanf` might work. The other part of my code is irrelevant because it just has a couple of printf functions that states the instructions to the user. I am more concerned with only this function. The code that you see posted is where I have gotten to so far as far as my most important function is concerned.

Comment: You are much better served reading the entire file with Airline code and ICAO identifiers into an `struct` *once*. Then you can query against the information in memory without the penalty of file I/O on each query. There are many examples on this site, and at least one regarding doing just that, reading ICAO and flight information from a file into a struct. (search this site for `'airline'` and `'acars'`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, we have not learned those yet in my class and my teacher does not want for us to get ahead and use things that were not taught. Any other methods that you think may work?

Comment: Fair enough, let us know if you run into more problems and we are happy to help you do it your way. The most important point is that you *slow down* and understand each piece of the puzzle your are assembling. `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have been doing this for the past hour or so. I was thinking that in the file there are a couple of lines where `str[0]` contains integers. However, I have `str[0]` as a character. Do you think this may have generated some problems?

Comment: You can compare the airline number as a *string*. You just have to compare it against a *string*, there is no need for conversion. If you read a line with `fgets` you can either loop and store the flight with (e.g. `char flight[8] = "", *f = flight, *p = str; while (*p != ',') { *f = *p++; f++; } *f = 0;` (you really don't need the affirmative *nul-termination* since you *initialized* `char flight[8] = ""`, it is already filled with *nul-bytes*, but it is always good habit to do). Now flight contains (e.g. `10A`), and you can use `if (strcmp (flight, airline) == 0) { .. matches ..}` to test.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! However, I get the following error when I compile: `warning: result of comparison against a string
      literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead)`

Comment: Well, that tells me you are passing one of the parameters to your `route` function that isn't correct. But it doesn't make a lot of sense (`strcmp` doesn't have a limitation on comparing literals) If your compiler or OS has some strange limitation, you can use `strncmp (flight, airline, strlen (flight))` in that case. One thing you need to do if you are going to learn C is to check the `man page` for each function you use unless you know it by heart. (e.g. [**strcmp(3)**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comments (and because it appears you need help to get the 'logic' light-bulb to wink on), let's take a look at what you are doing, and not doing, to get you sorted out. First let's look at your declaration:

```
void route(char *origin, char *destination, char *airline[]);
```

`void` is a horrible choice for a function type where you need some way to of gauging success/failure of the function (e.g. found/not-found in your case). Choose a `type` for `route` so you can **return** a value to indicate *success/failure* when required. `void` has its place, e.g. like in a simple function that just prints output where you validate the function parameters **before** passing them to the function. Otherwise, use a type where you can check a return value to determine if the function succeeded or failed. Here a simple `int` type is fine, returning `0` on failure and `1` (or any non-zero number, even negative) to indicate success.

Next, `char *airline[]` is an *array of pointers to type char*. This is not what you want to pass a string like `3A` which is an *array of type char* (which will be converted to a *pointer to char** when passed as a function parameter) or sting literal which is simply a *pointer to char*. So you actually want `char *airline` instead.

Next, unless you declare `fp` as a *global file stream pointer* (bad idea), you need to pass `FILE *fp` as a parameter to `route`. Putting this information together, your declaration for a usable `route` can be something like:

```
int route (char *origin, char *dest, char *airline, FILE *fp);
```

From what you describe in your question you are required to use `fgets`, but it is unclear on what you actually have available to parse the `airline`, `origin` and `destination` from `str` filled by `fgets`. So let's just assume you have no other functions you can use to separate the string and let's use the two basic methods that are always available (*array indexes* and *pointer arithmetic*) to parse `airline`, `origin` and `destination` from `str`.

This is the fundamental method of starting at the beginning of `str` and walking a pointer (or using array indexes) to check the value of each character and assign the characters (parse the words) as required until you have all the data you need, or reach the end of `str` (you must protect against either case).

When working down a string, it is up to *you* to keep track of where you are, and to anticipate to a reasonable degree what comes next, so you can test each character (for what you need, as well as for end of string), save it where it needs to be saved, or move on to saving it somewhere else. While you do this, you need to keep track of how many characters you have saved to each individual location (e.g. to separate character arrays, like `arln`, `org`, and `dst` to compare against the `airline`, `origin` and `destination` you are looking for) to insure you do not write beyond the end of any of the arrays, or allocated block of memory, remembering to save `+1 char` to hold the `'\0'` (*nul-byte* or *nul-terminating character*) at the end of each array or allocated block of memory to make each a *valid string*. (understand that `'\0'` the nul-byte has a character value of simply `0`, so you can use `'\0'` or simply `0` to terminate a string)

Rather than step through explaining each line of what a usable `route` function could look like, let me just provide a commented example that takes things step-by-step to help you understand the logic (and level of thought and understanding required to do virtually anything in C, you are provided complete control over how you use memory, and you have the complete responsibility to insure you use it correctly -- *with great power comes great responsibility*). Work though the following and let me know if you need help with any particular part.

I intentionally use both *array indexing* and *pointer arithmetic* in the example, but for a normal implementation of this type, I would prefer pointer arithmetic for the reason noted in the comments. All of the following can be done a number of different ways employing for example `fscanf` to simplify the read and parsing at once or by using `strtok`or `sscanf` to parse `str` filled by `fgets`. Those functions simply help you do what you can always do manually by walking a pointer (or pair of pointers) down any string.

I have validated the parameters passed to `route` in `route` as an example, but you would normally want to do that in the calling function (`main` here) before making your call to `route`. With that, here is an example of a usable `route` that will step though an input file containing lines formatted as:

```
airline, origin, destination  /* e.g. '3A, KOCH, KEGE' */
```

(the `commas` must be present at the end of each identifier as it is currently coded, but the number of spaces doesn't matter. `'  3A,   KOCH,        KEGE'` would work fine as well. You have complete control over this, and simply by changing the tests on each character, you could eliminate the `','` requirement altogether and just look for `0-9, a-z, A-Z` to make up each word -- it's all up to you.)

`route` will read each line in the data file with `fgets` parsing the individual identifiers into `arln`, `org` and `dst` to compare against `airline`, `origin` and `destination` passed to `route`, returning `1` if a match is found, or `0` on error or if no match is found. The example for `route`:

```
int route (char *origin, char *dest, char *airline, FILE *fp)
{
    /* validate parameters - you can do this before calling route */
    if (!origin || !*origin) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: origin 'NULL' or empty.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (!dest || !*dest) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: dest 'NULL' or empty.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (!airline || !*airline) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: airline 'NULL' or empty.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: fp not open for reading.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char str[LINE] = "";

    while (fgets (str, LINE, fp))  /* for each line in the input file */
    {
        char org[PARTS] = "", dst[PARTS] = "", arln[PARTS] = "",
            *o = org, *d = dst, *a = arln, *s = str;
        size_t n;

        /* check for trailing '\n' included by 'fgets' indicating 
         * complete line read into str, then remove '\n' by overwriting
         * with nul-terminating character.
         */
        n = strlen (str);
        if (str[n - 1] == '\n')
            str[--n] = 0;

        /* read airline flight from str into arln, will skip leading
         * whitespace copying all other chars up to first ',' or '\0'.
         * (you can also use strtok to 'tokenize' the line)
         */
        /* you can either use array indexing */
        for (n = 0; n < PARTS - 1 && s[n] && s[n] != ','; n++) {
            if (s[n] == ' ') continue;  /* skip space */
            a[n] = s[n];
        }
        a[n] = 0;   /* nul-terminate arln (already done, but...) */
        s += n;     /* indexing wont advance 's', advance to char after 'arln' 
                     * (to the ',') to start looking for beginning of 'org'.
                     */
        /* or use pointer arithmetic (cleaner as 's' is advanced)
         *
         * for (n = 0; n < PARTS - 1 && *s && *s != ','; n++, a++, s++) {
         *     if (*s != ' ') continue;
         *     *a = *s;
         * }
         * *a = 0;
         */

        /* add checks to validate 'arln' length here if desired, and the same
         * following filling 'org' and 'dst' if desired
         */

        /* compare arln to airline */
        if (strcmp (arln, airline) != 0)
            continue;   /* doesn't match, get next line */

        /* find start of origin (org) in str (using pointer arithmetic)
         * skipping forward until you find next '0-9', 'a-z' or 'A-Z'
         * (you can use while (*s && isalnum (*s)) from ctype.h instead)
         */
        while ( *s && ( (*s < '0' || '9' < *s) &&
                        (*s < 'a' || 'z' < *s) &&
                        (*s < 'A' || 'Z' < *s)))
            s++;

        if (!*s) {  /* validate you are not at end of str */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: no valid chars follow airline in str.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        /* fill org ICAO from str */
        for (n = 0; n < PARTS - 1 && *s && *s != ','; n++, o++, s++)
            *o = *s;
        *o = 0;

        /* compare org to origin */
        if (strcmp (org, origin) != 0)
            continue;   /* doesn't match, get next line */

        /* find start of destination (dst) in str (using pointer arithmetic)
         * skipping forward until you find next '0-9', 'a-z' or 'A-Z'
         * (you can use while (*s && isalnum (*s)) from ctype.h instead)
         */
        while ( *s && ( (*s < '0' || '9' < *s) &&
                        (*s < 'a' || 'z' < *s) &&
                        (*s < 'A' || 'Z' < *s)))
            s++;

        if (!*s) {  /* validate you are not at end of str */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: no valid chars follow origin in str.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        /* fill dst ICAO from str */
        for (n = 0; n < PARTS - 1 && *s && *s != ','; n++, d++, s++)
            *d = *s;
        *d = 0;

        /* compare dst to destination */
        if (strcmp (dst, dest) == 0)
            goto found;   /* match for airline, origin, destination found */
    }

    return 0;   /* return 0 - indicating no route found */

  found:

    return 1;   /* return 0 - indicating route found */
}
```

**Note:** `route` essentially does the same thing three times. Start at the beginning of each identifier, read each character into the proper array until a `','` (or *nul-byte) is found, *nul-terminate* your new array, then move to the next character in `str`, skip everything until an `0-9, a-z, A-Z` is found (beginning the next identifier), then repeat.

A short example of its use would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { PARTS = 8, LINE = 128 };  /* constants - adjust as required */

/* specify a meaningful return type to guage success/failure */
int route (char *origin, char *dest, char *airline, FILE *fp);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *ar = "3A", *or = "KOCH", *ds = "KEGE"; /* flight to find */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (route (or, ds, ar, fp))
        printf ("airline '%s' origin '%s' destination '%s' -- found.\n",
                ar, or, ds);
    else
        printf ("airline '%s' origin '%s' destination '%s' -- not found.\n",
                ar, or, ds);


    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}

int route (char *origin, char *dest, char *airline, FILE *fp)
{
    ...
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/route.txt
1D, KEFD, KPRS
3A, KOCH, KEGE
8Z, KDT0, 3T2
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/airline <dat/route.txt
airline '3A' origin 'KOCH' destination 'KEGE' -- found.
```

Work though the example, make sure you understand it all, let me know if you don't (after you have made reasonable search to answer the basic syntax, etc. questions your self)